# Flag an entire group if a single row meets a condition using data.table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I have the following sample data:

```
> so <- data.table(Credit_id = rep(c("1-A", "17-F", "2-D"), each = 3), Period = rep(1:3, times = 3), Due_days = c(0,0,0, 0,30,0, 0,30,60))
> so
   Credit_id Period Due_days
1:       1-A      1        0
2:       1-A      2        0
3:       1-A      3        0
4:      17-F      1        0
5:      17-F      2       30
6:      17-F      3        0
7:       2-D      1        0
8:       2-D      2       30
9:       2-D      3       60
```

The data shows how three different credits performed during their first three months in a portfolio. `Credit_id` is the main key, `Period` is a time index and `Due_days` shows how many days a client was overdue in a given period.

I want to create a new column `Flag` which can take two values: 0 and 1. `Flag` should take the value 1 if a credit (which is grouped by `Credit_id`) was ever equal to or greater than 30.

This is the result I want to get to:

```
   Credit_id Period Due_days Flag
1:       1-A      1        0    0
2:       1-A      2        0    0
3:       1-A      3        0    0
4:      17-F      1        0    1
5:      17-F      2       30    1
6:      17-F      3        0    1
7:       2-D      1        0    1
8:       2-D      2       30    1
9:       2-D      3       60    1
```

That is, assign a `1` to the groups who had at least one row where `Due_days >= 30`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
dt[, flag := +(any(Due_days >= 30)), by = Credit_id]

   Credit_id Period Due_days flag
1:       1-A      1        0    0
2:       1-A      2        0    0
3:       1-A      3        0    0
4:      17-F      1        0    1
5:      17-F      2       30    1
6:      17-F      3        0    1
7:       2-D      1        0    1
8:       2-D      2       30    1
9:       2-D      3       60    1
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
with(dt, ave(Due_days, Credit_id, FUN = function(x) +(any(x >= 30))))
```

`any()` tests whether at least one value per group fulfills the condition. As @Calum You already noted, `+` is just a quick way to transform a logical vector into a vector of integers.

To illustrate the use of `+`:

```
+(c(TRUE, FALSE))
[1] 1 0
```

Other possibilities are:

```
c(TRUE, FALSE) * 1
```

Or:

```
as.integer(c(TRUE, FALSE))
```

Comment: This is much more efficient than my typical approach. Thanks!

Would you mind elaborating on the syntax? Like, Why is there a `+` sign? I had never seen that before.

Comment: Not OP but this is just a fast way to convert the logical output of `any` to an integer. You could also use `as.integer` for readability if this is not familiar and you do not need the nanoseconds.

Comment: Awesome. So `+any(.)`is equivalente to `as.integer(any(.))`?

Comment: Yes, you can say it so :)